# Send "Error time out" after specific amount of time in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, http

I am making a API call but sometimes it is taking more time to get the response. I want to set a specific amount of time, lets say "8secs", to wait for the response if the time mention before has pass the API call should stop and show in console:

> "ERROR time out".

I have tried adding the timeout in a pipe as other posts says like this:

```
this.http.post<RefreshTokenResponseMessage>(url, tokenRequestMessage, { headers }).pipe(timeout(20)).toPromise()
```

but it is showing an error with the timeout there.

I also try adding the timeout param in the header like this:

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({authorization: 'Bearer ${sessionstorage.getItem('authData')}',timeout: '${2}',});
return this.httpClient.get(URL, { headers });
```

But I am also facing the same issue that it is not triggering the error.

Has anyone encounter something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to output a `console.error` if the http response has not arrived after 8 seconds, you can do this as follows:

```
this.http.post<RefreshTokenResponseMessage>(url, tokenRequestMessage, { headers }).pipe(
    tap((res) => console.log('Result:', res)),
    timeout(8000),
    catchError(_ => {
        console.error('ERROR time out');
        return EMPTY;
    })
)       
.subscribe();
```

Comment: Thank you! this is exactly what I needed, when I added the timeout before it was being import from a diferent package.